# Android Compress image and upload it to server using below code

Tags: java, php, android, upload

```
Hello greetings and salutation.
```

i have two different **Android codes** that almost work the same way. The first code Capture image from gallery and upload it with title to php server while the second code capture image from gallery and when resize button is pressed the image is compressed both size and memory is reduced but also maintaining the same picture Quality. Let me Upload / paste the two codes.

**But my question is**

how will i make the second code upload to server after it have compressed the image memory? or how will i make the first code before uploading to server let it compress it like code two ?

**The first code**

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androiduploadimage;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonChoose;

private EditText editText;
private ImageView imageView;

public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String KEY_TEXT = "name";
public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/PhotoUploadWithText/upload.php";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Bitmap bitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


public void uploadImage(){
    final String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
            param.put(KEY_TEXT,text);
            param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
            return result;
        }
    }
    UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
    u.execute();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonChoose){
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
```

}

**The second Code**

```
package id.zelory.compressor.sample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;

import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private ImageView actualImageView;
private ImageView compressedImageView;
private TextView actualSizeTextView;
private TextView compressedSizeTextView;
private File actualImage;
private File compressedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actualImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.actual_image);
    compressedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compressed_image);
    actualSizeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actual_size);
    compressedSizeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compressed_size);

    actualImageView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
    clearImage();
}

public void chooseImage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

public void compressImage(View view) {
    if (actualImage == null) {
        showError("Please choose an image!");
    } else {

        // Compress image in main thread
        //compressedImage = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(actualImage);
        //setCompressedImage();

        // Compress image to bitmap in main thread
        //compressedImageView.setImageBitmap(new Compressor(this).compressToBitmap(actualImage));

        // Compress image using RxJava in background thread
        new Compressor(this)
                .compressToFileAsFlowable(actualImage)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(File file) {
                        compressedImage = file;
                        setCompressedImage();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        showError(throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}

public void customCompressImage(View view) {
    if (actualImage == null) {
        showError("Please choose an image!");
    } else {
        // Compress image in main thread using custom Compressor
        try {
            compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
                    .setMaxWidth(640)
                    .setMaxHeight(480)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                    .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                    .compressToFile(actualImage);

            setCompressedImage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Compress image using RxJava in background thread with custom Compressor
        /*new Compressor(this)
                .setMaxWidth(640)
                .setMaxHeight(480)
                .setQuality(75)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                .compressToFileAsFlowable(actualImage)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(File file) {
                        compressedImage = file;
                        setCompressedImage();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        showError(throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });*/
    }
}

private void setCompressedImage() {
    compressedImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(compressedImage.getAbsolutePath()));
    compressedSizeTextView.setText(String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(compressedImage.length())));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Compressed image save in " + compressedImage.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Compressor", "Compressed image save in " + compressedImage.getPath());
}

private void clearImage() {
    actualImageView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
    compressedImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    compressedImageView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
    compressedSizeTextView.setText("Size : -");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            showError("Failed to open picture!");
            return;
        }
        try {
            actualImage = FileUtil.from(this, data.getData());
            actualImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(actualImage.getAbsolutePath()));
            actualSizeTextView.setText(String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(actualImage.length())));
            clearImage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            showError("Failed to read picture data!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void showError(String errorMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private int getRandomColor() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return Color.argb(100, rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
}

public String getReadableFileSize(long size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    final String[] units = new String[]{"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

}

Thanks seriously need this to be solved

Comment: Hello please how will i make the compressed image be uploaded to mysql

Comment: It is unclear -without looking at your code- what you try to upload. Files? If not: what do you consider to be an image?

Comment: i only want to upload image not file. the codes worked in different ways. the first one upload image to server while the second code compress. need to make it compress and upload

Comment: But what do you consider to be an image? What is it that you pick from gallery?

Comment: image is kinda a file

Comment: Please come to the point. Kinda is not exact.

Comment: they are lot of files with different file extensions so a narrowed mine to say image instead of file. so is it possible ?

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. If i read it correctly you can upload a file with some text. And you can first compress a file and then upload it. What do you want more?

Comment: i want it to compress and upload. the first code do not compress but the second code compress but not coded to upload to server

Comment: Then use the second code. Unclear what your problem is. Save the compressed image to file again. Then upload that compressed file.

Comment: then how will i make it to upload to server. Dude i explained this things correctly dont really know what you do not understand. i simply want the second code to upload to server like the first code or to make the first code compress and reduct file size like the second code before uploading

Comment: Then combine things. And if you cant then explain what the problem is.

Comment: just help me out and combine things

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

to this

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

this will work